# sql updating column of table whose values come by group by on other table column

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 table subtopics and userinteractionlog . subtopics have timespent column I want to update timespent column and the value come from userinteractionlog 
by using sum(datediff(mi,starttime,endtime)) group by SubTopicid

this is what I have tried but not working...

```
UPDATE subtopics s
SET timespent = 
( 
  SELECT SUM(DATEDIFF(mi,u.starttime,u.endtime))
  FROM Userinteractionlog u
  GROUP BY u.subtopicid HAVING s.idsubTopic=u.subtopicid
)
```

Comment: post your tables structure

Comment: How is it not working?  Is there an error message?  Are you getting the wrong values?

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE table Userinteractionlog
(
ID int
, starttime datetime
, endtime datetime
, subtopicid int
)
GO

INSERT INTO Userinteractionlog(ID,  starttime, endtime, subtopicid)
VALUES(1,   '2014-01-01 00:00:00.000',  '2014-03-02 00:00:00.000',  1)
,(2,    '2014-05-04 00:00:00.000',  '2014-06-06 12:00:00.000',  1)
,(3,    '2013-01-01 00:00:00.000',  '2013-01-02 00:00:00.000',  2)

CREATE TABLE subtopics
(
timespent bigint
, idsubTopic int
)
GO

INSERT INTO subtopics (timespent, idsubTopic)
VALUES
(NULL,  1)
,(NULL, 2)
GO

UPDATE subtopics
SET timespent = 
( 
  SELECT SUM(DATEDIFF(mi,u.starttime,u.endtime))
  FROM Userinteractionlog u
  GROUP BY u.subtopicid HAVING idsubTopic=u.subtopicid
)
GO
```

This returns

```
timespent   idsubTopic
134640       1
1440         2
```